# Why can't sbt resolve OpenIMAJ dependency?

Tags: scala, sbt, openimaj

Here is the **build.sbt** I use in a project:

```
name := "FaceReg"

version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.openimaj" % "image-processing" % "1.2.1"
```

While `update`ing the project, sbt reports `UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES`:

```
[info] Resolving org.openimaj#image-processing;1.2.1 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.openimaj#image-processing;1.2.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/org.openimaj/image-processing/1.2.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openimaj/image-processing/1.2.1/image-processing-1.2.1.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.openimaj#image-processing;1.2.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.openimaj#image-processing;1.2.1: not found
```

What could be issue? How to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OpenImaj has its own repository](http://sourceforge.net/p/openimaj/wiki/OpenIMAJ%20Library/) and does not publish artifacts to the maven central (that's one of the few repositories consulted by sbt by default).

Add the following `resolvers` to `build.sbt` to have the dependency resolved properly and you will be fine:

```
resolvers += "OpenIMAJ maven releases repository" at "http://maven.openimaj.org"

resolvers += "OpenIMAJ maven snapshots repository" at "http://snapshots.openimaj.org"
```

Also, make sure you use only `%` in artifact, not `%%` because right now it looks like you're targeting specific Scala version in dependency and it's not what you would want for OpenImaj.

Comment: same happens with maven too

Comment: @pamu why shouldn't it? (or, what precisely do you mean by saying "same"?)

Comment: i mean maven also fails if above dependency is used.

Comment: It is fine for me. Do you forget to do the reload :)

Comment: We'll be pushing release artefacts to maven central with the next release, but for the time being, as @Jacek said, you'll need to add an additional resolver to use http://maven.openimaj.org.